# Permission denied after encrypting file using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

Trying to add a password to a pdf using PyPDF2, but after encrypting the file, Permission denied error pops up. This is the code I'm using.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

# Add all pages to the writer
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

# Add a password to the new PDF
writer.encrypt("my-secret-password")

# Save the new PDF to a file
with open("encrypted-pdf.pdf", "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

Comment: Does Permission denied appear when you try to open the file, or where exactly?

Comment: Yes exactly when I try to open it using any editor such as acrobat etc.., it throws this error

Comment: I'm sorry to be stupid, is it because you've set a password? :\

Comment: Yes, I've encrypted it using a password as shown in the code above, but it doesn't even show a pop up or prompt for the password when I open it

Comment: Can you try opening the pdf in Chrome? What happens there?

Comment: Same error, permission denied, I've tried opening it in all editors

Comment: Can you post a minimal example produced using your writer?